# Unable to catch COMM_FAILURE exception (java)

Tags: java, ejb, corba

I´m communicating a standalone application with an EJB, if the server that holds the EJB is not turned on I receive a COMM_FAILURE like this one:

```
May 11, 2011 9:42:50 AM com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified initDelegates
INFO: Using com.sun.enterprise.transaction.jts.JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate as the delegate
org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 201  completed: No
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.connectFailure(ORBUtilSystemException.java:3431)
      ...
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:430)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at app.comercio.system.RemoteBeans.lookupProducts(RemoteBeans.java:33)
    at app.comercio.system.Controller.sendSpec(Controller.java:86)
    at app.comercio.view.Main.sendSpec(Main.java:175)
    at app.comercio.view.Main.main(Main.java:54)
```

I try to catch this exception on main, and I throw it on sendSpec, sendSpec and lookupProducts, however I don't know if this es effective because InitialContext.lookup only throws NamingException.
Is there a way to catch this exception?

Answer (score 2):

well this is a runtime exception so it won't be declared to be thrown but you can still catch it and handle it like any exception

```
   extended byjava.lang.Throwable
      extended byjava.lang.Exception
         extended byjava.lang.RuntimeException
              extended byorg.omg.CORBA.SystemException
                  extended byorg.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE
```